# Can not get jQuery's "queue" function to work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying to use the "queue" function of jQuery because it would pretty much fit to my use case (making sure that certain functions are run chained) but I can not get even a simple example to run. My code:

```
console.log("start");
$(document).queue("my", function (next) {
    console.log("hello");
    next();
});
```

Runing this coude, I see "start" but never "hello". The queue is never started.

Wrapping this in a "ready" or click event also does not work, what am I missing?

Comment: you didn't start the queue.

Comment: Really, but how do I start it?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/queue/ scroll about halfway down.

Comment: Check [**this**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.queue/) out! And [**this**](https://api.jquery.com/queue/).

Comment: Thx @PeterKA but if I found the answer in the documentation, I would not ask here.

Comment: We're pointing you to the documentation so that you can get more than a "Do This" explanation. No sense in recreating that all here.

Comment: Ok never mind but I actually read the documentation but it didn't help me in this particular question.

Comment: To be fair, the documentation alludes to `.dequeue()` in a way that isn't exactly clear.

Comment: The example(s) given in the documentation is usually a good place to start. Once you have it working, play around with it and adjust it bit by bit till it is close to what you want to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to call `.dequeue()` to get it going:

```
console.log("start");
$(document).queue("my", function (next) {
    console.log("hello");
    next();
}).dequeue("my");
```

This seems strange, but it allows you to build up a queue of operations separately from the act of starting the queue. You can make successive calls to `.queue()` passing the same queue name, and then nothing will happen until that `.dequeue("my")` call is made.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need something like this:

```
$(document).dequeue()
```

or

```
 $(document).queue("my", function (next) {
    console.log("hello");
    next();
}).dequeue("my");
```

Comment: Yes but it's important to pass in the queue name too.

Comment: get my point because obviously you didn't just copied/pasted Pointy's answer... :)